# Javascript - Is passing array[0] directly vs array[0] by i= 0 array[i] fundementally different inside an "if" statement?

Tags: javascript, coercion

Working on a programming challenge. The objective is to create a function that "Drop[s] the elements of an array (first argument), starting from the front, until the predicate (second argument) returns true."

```
dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {return n > 5;});

function dropElements(arr, func) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length-1; i++) {
        if(func(arr[i])) {
            break;
        }
        else { 
            arr.splice(i,1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

returns `[4]` which is the incorrect answer

However the following:

```
dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {return n > 5;});

function dropElements(arr, func) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (func(arr[0])) {
            break;
        } 
        else {
            arr.shift();
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr; 
}
```

returns `[]` which is the correct answer

I wrote it all out by hand and it looks like it should out put the same. Is it something to do with coercion that I don't understand?

Comment: What's the point of incrementing `i` if you're always going to decrement it in the `else` clause?

Comment: There's really no point in using a `for()` loop at all in your code, since `i--` and `i++` undo each other. Just use `while(arr.length > 0)` to loop until the `break` is done or you've removed everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first loop is up to `arr.length-1` while the second is `arr.length`.

Comment: Oh man! Thanks! I thought it was loosing my mind, glad it was just a syntax error ><